# Laravel 4 Advanced Search Query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I've created a search form with several optional fields but when trying to include these as part of a query in the controller it returns no results

```
$active = Input::get('active');
$field  = Input::get('field');
$value  = Input::get('value');

$claims = Claim::where($field, $value);

if($active != 'All')
{
    $claims->where('active', $active);
}

$claims->get();

return View::make('admin.search.results')->with('claims', $claims);
```

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you try this as a raw SQL query and see if you get results then?

Comment: I tried changing the first query line to: $claims = DB::table('claims')->where($field, $value);

Comment: But then I just get a Trying to get property of non-object error

Comment: I mean as a raw SQL query, not PHP. If you have tool like phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench use it to make a select query and see if you get results.

Comment: I know the query would return results because it does if I include it all chained together in one e.g. $claims = Claim::where($field, $value)->get();

Comment: Its only when I separate the ->get() that it stops working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$claims = Claim::where($field, $value);

if($active != 'All') {
    $claims = $claims->where('active', $active);
}

$claims = $claims->get();
```

Comment: That's kind of working....it returns a different error that the view is trying to access an undefined property.

Comment: If I remove the line <td>{{ $claim->lead_user->first_name.' '.$claim->lead_user->last_name }}</td> from my view it works

Comment: Is it not possible to access related models when building up queries this way?

Comment: @user1105056 you should have no problem accessing the relations of the *Claim* model.

Comment: Ah I'd changed the first line to DB::table('claims')->where($field, $value); when playing around with it. The above code works, thanks!